# Response from json is coming empy

Tags: python

I am using request library to get a response in python. I need to check if the response from the API is empty . If the response is empty I need to not append to a array. If the response is not empty then i will append to the array. Can somebody please help me on this

I need to check if `r.text` is null or not.

```
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
  r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS ,headers={"X-Api-Key":"123"}) 

  print(r.text)
# extracting data in json format
  data = r.json()[0]
  print(data)
  json_arr.append(data)
```

Comment: What exactly would an empty response be? No returned data, or an empty JSON array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the length of the object if superior to 0 :

```
data = r.json()[0]
print(data)
if len(data) > 0:
    json_arr.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
if r.text:
    data = r.json()[0]
    json_arr.append(data)
```

simple if statement will check for empty string and null value.